# VBA compile error due to "ByRef argument type mismatch"

Tags: vba, arguments, byref

I have this VBA code:

```
codes = regexSearch("Response Codes: (.+)[\W$]", email.Body)
MsgBox ("Codes is >>>" & codes & "<<<")
MsgBox ("Codes type is " & VarType(codes))
codes = Left(codes, Len(codes) - 1)
MsgBox ("Codes is >>>" & codes & "<<<")
msgCount = regexSearch(".+:\W+(\d+)", codes)
```

and my 'regexSearch' subroutine, (which works just fine in 30 or 40 other places) is defined as:

```
Function regexSearch(pattern As String, argument As String)
```

The body of my email contains:

> Moneta IBS via VPMG Response Codes: 911: 202 Severity: 1

When I run the VBA againast the email, I get:

[image: Compile error]

If I remove the offending line and let the MsgBox diagnostics run, I see that:

[image: 'Codes' value]

with the ending CR/LF.

The subsequent MsgBoxes state that 'Codes type is 8' (String), then 'Codes is >>>911:202<<<'

substituting "911: 202" for `codes` in `msgCount = regexSearch(".+:\W+(\d+)", codes)` and it works.

What is causing the argument type mismatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`codes` is probably declared as `Variant` while `regexSearch` expects an `String`. While a Variant *can* hold a String, it can also contain any other data type and therefore is not a valid argument if a String is expected.

You can solve this by either declaring `codes` as String (if this is feasable in your case) or convert the content to a String when you call `regexSearch`

```
msgCount = regexSearch(".+:\W+(\d+)", CStr(codes))
```

Comment: So VarType can return 8 (String) even if the variable is Varient?

Comment: The variable is Variant. The current content *might* be a string - in that case `VarType` returns 8 (at runtime). But your error is at compile time, not at runtime. The compiler cannot predict the type in advance.

Comment: Thanks Thomas - that makes sense. I'll look into using Option Explicit too.